# How to replace the following code in Java 8?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

```
private void createAnagramSignatures() {
    for (String word : dictionary.keySet()) {
        int signature = getSignature(word);
        if (!anagramMap.containsKey(signature)) {
            anagramMap.put(signature, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        anagramMap.get(signature).add(word);
    }
}
```

I am somewhat familiar with map.getOrDefault, just not sure how it can be applied in the following scenario.

Comment: You could try to replace your enhanced for loop with a stream, but honestly I would rather read and maintain the version your currently have.  Some possibly weird logic going on with your initializing the list inside the map, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do that would be using `computeIfAbsent`, you can perform it as :

```
dictionary.keySet()
        .forEach(word -> anagramMap.computeIfAbsent(getSignature(word),
                key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(word));
```

Comment: This Answer perfectley resembles what Tim Biegeleisen is saying. Some stuff just shouldn't be refactored to a lambda expression. I find the upper much easier to read and understand.

Comment: @kaba713 Well readability might be opinion based in that case. For me(my opinion), the API just reads it out loud, `computeIfAbsent` while on the other hand the `if` and the `add` bit in the OP's code does the same action as well.